# h3 и a в один ряд (Bootstrap, CSS)

Tags: css

Доброй ночи! Я разбираюсь с Bootstrap'ом и не могу понять, поставил h3 и a

Разметка:

```
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <div id="rightsidemenu" class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-9">
            <ul>
                <li><a class="onhead" href="#">Вход</a></li>
                <li><a class="onhead">|</a></li>
                <li><a class="onhead" href="#">Регистрация</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>  
        <div id="center" class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-4">
            <h3 class="main">Все заявки и поставщики в одном месте!</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
a.onhead{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  }

  a.onhead:hover{
  color: #a9aaac;
  transition: 1s;
  }

  li {
  display: inline;
  list-style-type: none;
  }

  h3.main{
  display: inline;
  text-decoration: none;
  }
```

Как сделать их в один ряд? Никак не могу понять :D

[image: 123]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас изначально не правильная `html` структура.

Пример как лучше оформить:

```css
a.onhead{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 0;
}

a.onhead:hover{
  color: #a9aaac;
  transition: 1s;
}

h3.main{
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<div class="container">
  <div id="header">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="rightsidemenu" class="col-md-3 col-md-push-9">
        <ul class="list-inline">
          <li><a class="onhead" href="#">Вход</a></li>
          <li><a class="onhead">|</a></li>
          <li><a class="onhead" href="#">Регистрация</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>  
      <div id="center" class="col-md-9 col-md-pull-3">
        <h3 class="main">Все заявки и поставщики в одном месте!</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

и тогда для того чтобы выровнять на одном уровне заголовок и список, достаточно будет добавить отступы (padding) для ссылок или `li` или `ul` (это уже как пожелаете, я задала для ссылок для примера), либо задать `line-height`.

Answer (score 0):

*Примерно* так (можно настраивать расположение по необходимости), с использованием `push` и `pull`:

```
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <div id="rightsidemenu" class="col-md-7 col-md-push-9">
            <ul>
                <li><a class="onhead" href="#">Вход</a></li>
                <li><a class="onhead">|</a></li>
                <li><a class="onhead" href="#">Регистрация</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>  
        <div  class="col-md-5 col-md-pull-3">
            <h3 class="main">Все заявки и поставщики в одном месте!</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Сумма числовых значений соответствующих колонок не должна превышать 12, иначе возможны варианты (каждый свободен проэкспериментировать).
http://www.bootply.com/ofsU7W532Y